# How to get multiple query results in a single field/cell from a join statement

Tags: mysql

I have like 5 tables I am joining for this, but Ill simplify my explanation to what I need.

I have a table for "People" With their ID, and name, and age

A table for "borrow records" which has 1 record per borrowed book: record_id, person_id, book_id (There are no repeats, a person only ever borrows the same book once)

A table for "Books" which has their id, and title

And I want a CSV export that gives me:
People over 18 years old.

- Their name
- Their ID
- Their Age
- Name of all the books they have borrowed (IE: "Alice in wonderland, Superman comic1")

4 columns.

I know how to do the joins and how to do the WHERE for the age. But I have no idea how to get all the book titles a person has ever borrowed in a single cell. I am looking for a result like:

Pedro||id7||22||"Last unicorn, lord of the rings"

George||id5||30||"The hobbit, Last man on earth, little women"

The database is a Drupal database where I am trying to get taxonomy names from a taxonomy field in particular nodes. But I explained it with book/people for people who are not familiar with Drupal.

Comment: Where have you planed to schedule this request? Pay attention to the Drupal cache management system and do not execute this query too often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` like this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.id, p.age, GROUP_CONCAT(b.title)
FROM People p
  JOIN borrow_records br
 ON p.id=br.person_id
  JOIN Books b
 ON br.book_id=b.id
GROUP BY p.name, p.id, p.age
```

Here's a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6zFBTX74)